# Twitter Bootstrap Rails - Gem Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, gemfile

When trying to install a rails gem that ships the twitter-bootstrap-rails into my application, I got the following issue:

> C:\workinrails\mytrelloapp>bundle install
>   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
>     In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       railties (= 4.2.5.1)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
>         railties (< 5.1.x, >= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32
>
> jquery-rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
>         railties (>= 4.2.0) x86-mingw32
>
> rails (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.5.1, which depends on
>         railties (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32
>
> sass-rails (~> 5.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
>         railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32
>
> twitter-bootstrap-rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
>         railties (>= 5.0.1, ~> 5.0) x86-mingw32
>
> web-console (~> 2.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
>         railties (>= 4.0) x86-mingw32

After getting this "Running bundle update will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict." message, I got a new issue telling me that Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack"

To summarize, I just did these steps:

Step 1 - Pasted gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' to my gemfile.

Step 2 - Bundle install

And I was hoping to arrive to Step 3 - rails generate bootstrap:install static

What's the issue?

Comment: have you tried it without the the :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git line?

Comment: Thanks man, I think it works. But strange, I just religiously followed the provided documentation. Still, don't know what's the difference between having that line or not.

Comment: Stuff thats on the the companies github isn't always in/ready for the the production version of the gem yet so I could have been that or it could have been some version issue. Generally you don't need to point to a git repo for a gem unless there's some feature you need that they haven't released yet